# AppMetrics how to set application name?

Tags: c#, .net, metrics

I implemented App.Metrics into my wcf application (App.Metrics ver 3.1.0).
When I check url in which data is uploaded I found that *app* isn't filled:
[image]

Tried to figured out reason of this behavior I found manual: 
https://www.app-metrics.io/getting-started/fundamentals/tagging-organizing/

It said that AssemblyName needs to be filled, but I double-checked it - csproj file contain next row:

```
<AssemblyName>MyWebService</AssemblyName>
```

How can I fill this *app* property in metrics?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

startup.cs:

```
var metrics = MetricsProvider.Instance.Metrics;
SetMetricsAppTag(metrics, Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Name);   

private static void SetMetricsAppTag(IMetricsRoot metricsRoot, string appTagValue)
{
     if (!metricsRoot.Options.GlobalTags.ContainsKey("app"))
     {
           metricsRoot.Options.GlobalTags.Add("app", appTagValue);
     }
     else if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(metricsRoot.Options.GlobalTags["app"]) || metricsRoot.Options.GlobalTags["app"] == "unknown")
     {
           metricsRoot.Options.GlobalTags["app"] = appTagValue;
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

a better way will be to do in startup-

```
var metrics = AppMetrics.CreateDefaultBuilder().
                Configuration.
                Configure(options => options.AddAppTag(appName: "nexus"))
               .Build();
            services.AddMetrics(metrics);
            services.AddMetricsTrackingMiddleware();
            services.AddMetricsEndpoints(opt =>
            {
                opt.MetricsTextEndpointOutputFormatter = new MetricsPrometheusTextOutputFormatter();
                opt.MetricsEndpointOutputFormatter = new MetricsPrometheusProtobufOutputFormatter();
                opt.EnvironmentInfoEndpointEnabled = false;
            });
```